# Contracted indices can be interchanged?

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, notation

I am working on Lorentz transformations and I get a tensor of the form
$$M_{abcd}=\epsilon_{ab\mu\nu}\Lambda^\mu\hspace{0.1cm}_c\Lambda^\nu\hspace{0.1cm}_d$$
Where $\epsilon_{abμν}$ is the totally antisymmetric (pseudo-)tensor of Levi-Civita.
Is it posible to interchange contracted indices so that I can get
$$M_{abdc}=\epsilon_{ab\mu\nu}\Lambda^\mu\hspace{0.1cm}_d\Lambda^\nu\hspace{0.1cm}_c=-\epsilon_{ab\nu\mu}\Lambda^\mu\hspace{0.1cm}_d\Lambda^\nu\hspace{0.1cm}_c=-M_{abcd}$$
Also it is posible to check if $M_{abcd}=uM_{cdab}$ with $u=\pm1$

Answer (score 0):

The contracted indices are just dummies, indicating a sum. They have no intrinsic meaning.
Interchanging them just corresponds to changing their (insignificant) names.  What you do is perfectly correct.

The tensor M is completely antisymmetric.  To go from abcd to dcab involves four interchanges, so u=+1.

Comment: Can you explicitly prove the antisymmetry of $M$ in the second and third indices?

Comment: I see what you mean.  I took the bait.  M is not completely antisymmetric. $M_{abcd}$ has no relation to $M_{cdab}$, unless more is known about $\Lambda$.